# Getting object instead of string of URL from react-native-firebase/dynamicLinks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am trying to get a  URL for my user.

```
export default function InvitationLink (){
        async function CreateLink(){
            await dynamicLinks().buildShortLink(
                {
                    link:"https://demoproject.com/?invitedby="+user+uid ,
                    domainUriPrefix:"https://demoproject.page.link",
                    android:{
                        minimumVersion:"124",
                        fallbackUrl:"www.google.com",
                        packageName:"com.demoproject.android"
                    }
                }
            ).then((newLink) =>{
                console.log("Created link: ",newLink); // Output:  Created link:  https://demoproject.page.link/xYan8S7xjTTB7aLQ6
                return newLink
            })
            
            
        }

        const GenerateLink = () =>{
            const newLink = CreateLink();
            console.log("Generated Link : ",newLink)  // output:  Generated Link :  {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}
            return <Text>Link Created</Text>
        }

        return(
            <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'column', justifyContent:"center", alignItems:'center', borderColor:'black', borderWidth:5 }}>
                <GenerateLink/>
            </View>
        )
    }
```

Instead of URL it was throwing object.
Actual output: {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}
Expected Output: https://demoproject.page.link/xYan8S7xjTTB7aLQ6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues with the code as I can see.

We must have to specify the wait for async function calls by using then or async / await.

If we are not providing such a wait for async functions and processing data after the function call without waiting for a response then we might get a null object as you are getting now.

Also, we cannot use the async functions as our react components for render asynchronously. for this, we can use the state to update our component at run time.

Must try with the code I am providing below with some modification to your existing code :

```
export default function InvitationLink (){

   const [dynamicLink, setDynamicLink] = useState("")

    async function CreateLink(){
        await dynamicLinks().buildShortLink(
            {
                link:"https://demoproject.com/?invitedby="+user+uid ,
                domainUriPrefix:"https://demoproject.page.link",
                android:{
                    minimumVersion:"124",
                    fallbackUrl:"www.google.com",
                    packageName:"com.demoproject.android"
                }
            }
        ).then((newLink) =>{
            console.log("Created link: ",newLink); // Output:  Created link:  https://demoproject.page.link/xYan8S7xjTTB7aLQ6
            return newLink
        }).catch((err) => {
            return `Error + ${err.message}`
        })
        
        
    }

    const GenerateLink = async () =>{
        try {
            const newLink = await CreateLink();
            console.log("Generated Link : ",newLink)  // output:  must be a string url
            setDynamicLink(newLink)
        } catch(err) { // handle issue if we got issue in CreateLink function call
            console.log("Error ": err)
            setDynamicLink("Error at creating dynamic link")
        }
        
    }

    return(
        <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'column', justifyContent:"center", alignItems:'center', borderColor:'black', borderWidth:5 }}>
            <Text>{dynamicLink}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export default function InvitationLink() {
  async function CreateLink() {
    const newLink = await dynamicLinks().buildShortLink({
      link: "https://demoproject.com/?invitedby=" + user + uid,
      domainUriPrefix: "https://demoproject.page.link",
      android: {
        minimumVersion: "124",
        fallbackUrl: "www.google.com",
        packageName: "com.demoproject.android",
      },
    });
    console.log("Created link: ", newLink); // Output:  Created link:  https://demoproject.page.link/xYan8S7xjTTB7aLQ6
    return newLink;
  }

  const GenerateLink = () => {
    const newLink = await CreateLink();
    console.log("Generated Link : ", newLink); // output:  Generated Link :  {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}
    return <Text>Link Created</Text>;
  };

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        borderColor: "black",
        borderWidth: 5,
      }}
    >
      <GenerateLink />
    </View>
  );
}
```

This should be work fine.